# Install Pluma in Xubuntu

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu

Anybody knows how to install pluma in xubuntu. Mousepad is really a crappy text editor, though leafpad helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install pluma
```

And *Pluma* is installed.

[image]

Comment: Gefündenes Fressen!  ;-)

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package pluma` -- any PPA that we might have to add for that?